# Save animation clips and play them for a time

Tags: animation

I know that my title doesnt explains very well my problem.

I would like to know if there is a way to do some animations in different clips and then in a general animation say, play that clip (that is loop) for x frames, and if it finishes it starts again.

For example, a character. You make an animation of it walking that is 20 frames, and you want to play it 40, another 20 of other action and another 60 of it walking.
There is a way of doing that properly?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Go to the NLA Editor, with your object or armature selected.  You will find your object listed along with its animation on the left.  Click the double arrow button, and the animation is converted into a strip on the timeline shown in the NLA editor.  Now you can duplicate the strip to continue the animation in any part of the timeline!

Comment: Could I get a more detailed answer or a video? I have this: https://gyazo.com/14b812e78a3c6b6106adb50fa14b3cb0

Comment: Ok, see the grey button next to the text "CtrlPistolAction"?  Press that, and you will have an animation strip instead.  I use version 2.79, so it looks a little different for me.  Say if you need anything else